Exercise 2 in Chapter 1 of Apostol's "Modular Functions and Dirichlet series in Number Theory"
I am reading the book in the title and I don't know how to prove the following (that is Exercise 2 in Chapter 1):
Suppose $f$ is an elliptic function (meaning that $f$ is meromorphic and there are two complex numbers $\omega_1, \omega_2$ that are both periods for $f$ and such that $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is not real) and let $S(0)$ be the sum of all the zeros inside the parallelogram determined by $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, and $S(\infty)$ be the sum of all the poles in the same parallelogram. Then $S(0)-S(\infty)$ is a period of $f$. The hint is to integrate $zf'(z)/f(z)$ but when I do that I get zero and don't know what to do next.
Following the comment, I am editing the question to describe my computation of the integral of $zf'(z)/f(z)$ along the boundary of a parallellogram with vertices at $z_1$, $z_2=z_1+\omega_1$, $z_3=z_1+\omega_1+\omega_2$, $z_4=z_1+\omega_2$.
Integrating by parts $zf'(z)/f(z) = z (\log(f(z))'$, and using the periodicity of $f$, the integral from  $z_1$ to $z_2$ is $\omega_1 \log(f(z_1)) - \int_{z_1}^{z_2} \log(f(z))dz$ while the one from $z_3$ to $z_4$ is $-\omega_1 log(f(z_1)) -\int_{z_2}^{z_1}\log(f(z))dz$  so the two cancel out. In the same way, the integrals from $z_2$ to $z_3$ and from $z_4$ to $z_1$ will cancel. If the integrand were $f'(z)/f(z)$ instead of $zf'(z)/f(z)$, it's a standard fact from complex analysis that the integral is the number of zeros minus  the number of poles of $f$ (counted with multiplicity), and in fact this is used in a theorem in the book to prove that the number of zeros is equal to the number of poles, because by periodicity the integral is zero. So I am expecting that some modification of the argument should be used for this exercise.

If you write out your computation of the integral of $z f'/f$, it will facilitate someone to come and answer.

We will assume that $f$ has no poles or zeros in the boundary of the fundamental parallellogram $P_0$. If there were, we can consider $P_a=a+P_0$ for a suitable complex number $a$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_n,b_1,\dots,b_n$ be zeros and poles of $f$ respectively. Arguing similar with the proof of the argument principle, we get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial P_0}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k-b_k,$$
where the integration is counter clockwise. Therefore we need to prove $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial P_0}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz\in \omega_1\mathbb{Z}+\omega_2\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the parallel sides of $P_0$, let $\gamma_1$ be the side from $0$ to $\omega_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be the side from $\omega_1+\omega_2$ to $\omega_2$. Then we have
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}\right)\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{0}^{\omega_1}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz-\int_{0}^{\omega_1}\frac{(\omega_2+z)f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\right)=\frac{-\omega_2}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\omega_1}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$$ where we used the $\omega_2$ periodicity of $f$ and $f'$. Let the curve $f([0,\omega_1])$ be $\Omega_1$. Then the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\omega_1}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ equals $\text{Ind}_{\Omega_1}(0)$ which is an integer. Hence we get $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}\right)\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz\in \omega_2\mathbb{Z}$. By the identical symmetric argument $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{\Gamma_1}+\int_{\Gamma_2}\right)\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz\in \omega_1\mathbb{Z}$ where $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ are the other 2 sides of $P_0$. Finally, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial P_0}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{\gamma_1}+\int_{\gamma_2}+\int_{\Gamma_1}+\int_{\Gamma_2}\right)\in\omega_1\mathbb{Z}+\omega_2\mathbb{Z},$$
which was to be shown.
